# When installing Haskell, dependency is not satisfiable: ghc6 (< 6.12.1+)

Tags: 11.04, package-management, haskell

What does that mean, can I not install haskell? I just upgraded to Natty, is that the reason?

As you can see in the screenshot I get this problem in the Software Centre:

[image]

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

haskell-platform: Depends: ghc6 (< 6.12.1+) but 6.12.3-1ubuntu7 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-cgi-dev (>= 3001.1.7.2) but 3001.1.7.2-1build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-fgl-dev (< 5.4.2.2+) but 5.4.2.2-2build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-glut-dev (< 2.1.2.1+) but 2.1.2.1-1build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-haskell-src-dev (< 1.0.1.3+) but 1.0.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-html-dev (< 1.0.1.2+) but 1.0.1.2-3build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-hunit-dev (< 1.2.2.1+) but 1.2.2.1-2build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-mtl-dev (< 1.1.0.2+) but 1.1.0.2-10build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-network-dev (< 2.2.1.7+) but 2.2.1.7-1build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-opengl-dev (< 2.2.3.0+) but 2.2.3.0-2build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-parallel-dev (< 2.2.0.1+) but 2.2.0.1-1build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-parsec2-dev (< 2.1.0.1+) but 2.1.0.1-2build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-quickcheck2-dev (< 2.1.0.3+) but 2.1.0.3-1build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-regex-base-dev (< 0.93.1+) but 0.93.1-8build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-regex-compat-dev (< 0.92+) but 0.92-6build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-regex-posix-dev (< 0.94.1+) but 0.94.1-2build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-stm-dev (< 2.1.1.2+) but 2.1.1.2-5build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-xhtml-dev (>= 3000.2.0.1) but 3000.2.0.1-6build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-zlib-dev (< 0.5.2.0+) but 0.5.2.0-4build2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-http-dev (>= 40000009) but 40000009-2build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libghc6-deepseq-dev (< 1.1.0.0+) but 1.1.0.0-2build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: alex (< 2.3.3+) but 2.3.3-1 is to be installed
                  Depends: happy (< 1.18.4-2+) but 1.18.4-2 is to be installed
                  Depends: haddock but it is a virtual package
```

Comment: This is now fixed and in -proposed. See the following answer for more details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44709/how-can-i-install-haskell-platform/44750#44750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because of a bug introduced in Natty; this is [Bug #742052](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/haskell-platform/+bug/742052).

Unfortunately there's not much you can easily do to get around this.

Comment: I did try that, the same problem. Look at the picture in my updated post.

Comment: @Blub I've updated my answer

Comment: that is kind of a big deal

Answer (score 1):

There is a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/haskell-platform/+bug/742052/comments/12) for this problem:

Use `vi` and edit the file `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`
Find the string `6.12.1+` and change it to `6.12.4+`
Save the change and `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` will still fail while calling some post-install-script, but it seems usable.