# How can I install haskell-platform?

Tags: 11.04, haskell

Haskell-platform currently has unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 11.04. This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/haskell-platform/+bug/742052), but I'd like to get it installed sooner rather than later.

Can anyone recommend a way to install haskell-platform on 11.04? The bug report that I linked to offers a solution that requires editing a binary package (?) using vim, but I'd rather install something from source than go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has now been fixed and is in 11.04 -proposed. Therefor you can enable proposed packages and install haskell-platform. If you do not want to keep getting -proposed updates you can disable it once you have haskell-platform installed. Look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) for a guide on how to enable -proposed updates.

This bug is fixed in 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you are out of options for the moment besides compiling it yourself (but editing the package seems alot less problematic).

Either you edit `var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` as shown at [comment #12 in the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/haskell-platform/+bug/742052/comments/12) or you will have to wait until all the problems have been ironed out for using the Haskell platform on Ubuntu 11.04

I would go with editing the package. It is not that difficult and I expect you to be able to do that without any problem.

edit: now I am on my own machine.

```
cd /var/cache/apt/
sudo cp pkgcache.bin pkgcache.backup.bin
sudo cp pkgcache.bin pkgcache.test.bin
sudo vi pkgcache.test.bin
```

<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
/6.12.1+
```

This will result in:

```
009fe21547b0cc8fc2f7ee1ec74d3e27^@haskell-http-doc^@1:2^@libghc6-http-
doc^@^@009fe21547b0cc8fc2f7ee1ec74d3e27^@2.7.0-
2^@xemacs22^@^@b8b7ecd2f37fbc271d0108a704c42056^@haskell-pcre-light-doc^@1:2^@libghc6-
pcre-light-doc^@^@009fe21547b0cc8fc2f7ee1ec74d3e27^@haskell-
platform^@2010.1.0.0.1^@6.12.1^@6.12.1+^@libghc6-cgi-dev^
```

See the 6.12.1 at the bottom?

Navigate with the arrow keys to the 1 of `.1+`
When on the 1 hit `r` `4` `:wq!`

That's the practise run. Remove the `.test` from the `sudo vi pkgcache.test.bin` to change the real file. After that install it in the normal way.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, I know that you were the one who edited the package. Have you been using Haskell since installing in that way, and have you encountered any problems with Haskell as a result?

Comment: @j1mc no I have not. I editted in the commands you need to use to edit the pkgcache.bin I think I did it correctly. Have a try yourself. If it gets you haskell working please leave feedback ;)

Comment: This worked for me, errored on the post-install script as the original bug said.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling it from source - http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/linux.html

Comment: I gave the "compile it from source" option a try, and things have been fine so far. Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from the following PPA: https://launchpad.net/~brcha/+archive/ppa
Here's how:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brcha/ppa
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

Voila!

Comment: First, python-software-properties must be installed. `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`. Second, after the ppa repository is added, the package list must be updated. `sudo apt-get update`. Third, the brcha repository is currently down, so `sudo apt-get update` fails to find the brcha package list and `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` fails to find haskell-platform. Maybe there's another ppa repository that does work for Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a small Haskell course right now and I've created Natty Live CDs for the course participants. What I've done is add all the packages I needed(and which would go with the platform anyway) without the haskell-platform package. Everything else I needed, I installed with cabal-install.

This may not be the perfect solution but it works for me.

Shipping a broken package was very lame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ditto. http://www.yellosoft.us/gak

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this out?
http://sporkcode.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/installing-the-haskell-platform-in-ubuntu/

If you are using 64bit UBUNTU please check comments to resolve some problems ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.